# Controlling Manipulate in cloud deployment

Tags: manipulate, interface, interactive, cloud-deploy

Suppose I want to create a web app which duplicates (for simplicity), something like

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, Pi}], {n, 3, 10, 1}]
```

`FormFunction` seems similar, but I can't see how to give it ranges of values. This must be trivial...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read examples in docs carefully (CloudDeploy, FormFunction, FormPage) and see related tutorials. Two options.

**1) Outsource control to FormFunction / FormPage:**

```
CloudDeploy[
    FormPage[
        {"n" -><|"Interpreter" -> Restricted["Real",{3,10}], "Control" -> Slider|>}, 
        Plot[Sin[#n x],{x,0,Pi}]&],
"test"]
```

**2) Keep control in Manipulate and simply CloudDeploy:**

```
CloudDeploy[Manipulate[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, Pi}], {n, 3, 10}], "tmp"]
```

Comment: Cool! That is perfect!